# Display image asset of a variant

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Craft Commerce newbie question....

How do I display the image asset for a custom variant field?

I'd like to display the associated image of a product variant in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so in general this depends on if the custom field is on the product or the variant.   Assume the filed is called `masterImage` either way.

If the field is on a variant:
`{% set image = lineItem.purchasable.product.masterImage.first() %}`

If the field is on the product:
`{% set image = lineItem.purchasable.masterImage.first() %}`

Remember (either way) you should always check there is an image first really:

`{% if lineItem.purchasable.product.masterImage|length %} ... set the image`

In practise I usually have code that falls back to the product image if the variant image is not set for whatever reason:

```
    {% set image = lineItem.purchasable.masterImage.first() ?? null %}
    {# Fallback on product image if there is no variant image set #}
    {% if not image|length %}
        {% set image = lineItem.purchasable.product.masterImage.first() ?? null %}
    {% endif %}
```

(Note here I am not doing the initial test on the asset because I am instead using the null coalescing operator)

Comment: Okay, so I have tried displaying the field on the variant with:

Comment: But an error returns with `Variable "lineItem" does not exist`

Comment: Yep you will need to loop through the line items ... Check the Commerce docs on order models...I'm in a taxi ;)

Comment: I'm currently doing so with `{% for item in cart.lineItems %}`

Comment: Change it to for lineItem in...

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Nice answer. You could also set fall back to a placeholder image as well if the site is expecting one and it doesn't exist.  Set up a global with an asset field like ``defaultProductVariantImage``. ``{{lineItem.purchasable.product.masterImage.first()|default(siteGlobals. defaultProductVariantImage.first) }}``

Comment: Yep that's a good idea too.  In my case I send all images to a macro which has a fallback so that step comes after and is more globally addressed :)