# Product Variant Detail Page

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I guess this is no big issue, but I'm pretty new to Craft Commerce :)
I'm trying to code a dynamic template for the product variants page.

This is the scenario: In the shop overview you see every product and all there variants. If you click on a variant image a detail page opens, showing you detailed information about this variant.

How can I access data of the variant (like title, description, asset) dynamically? Based on what the user clicked on?

I've already tried these two answers:

[How do I select a specific product variant by element/field/entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12708/how-do-i-select-a-specific-product-variant-by-element-field-entry)

[Display image asset of a variant](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17263/display-image-asset-of-a-variant)

The thing is, I can't use lineItem because the variant is not added to the cart yet. And I didn't manage to get the specific variant over getSegment and the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can check for available variants, then output whatever detail you need for the items. Something like this should get you started:

```
{# Check there are variants #}
{% if product.variants|length %}

  {# Loop through the variants #}
  {%- for purchasable in product.variants -%}

    {# Check the variant is available #}
    {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.unlimitedStock == false %}

      {{ purchasable.description }}
      {{ purchasable.salePrice|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}

    {% endif %}
  {%- endfor -%}

  {% else %}
    {{ "Out of Stock"|t }}
  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

If you want to target only a specific variant you can refer to it directly using either its title (slug) or its variant ID, e.g.:

```
{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants.id(8376).first() %}
```

You can find more detail in [the docs for the Variant Model](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/variant-model) and [the docs for Craft Commerce Variants](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-variants).

Comment: Thank you! This goes into the right direction, it outputs all variants. But is there a way do output one specific variant? Based on the slug or ID for example? I'm thinking of something like this `{% set variantSlug = craft.request.getSegment(4) %}`but I still only get the product (=all variants), not just a specific one.

Comment: Sure! I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If my answer helped then perhaps you can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Of course! Will do so